# What is the max. upstream rate of Annex A modem using ADSL2+ (ITU G.992.5)?

Tags: networking, adsl2+

Sources show 1 Mbps up to 3 Mbps. So what? I'm not talking from Annex M which seems to support more (3 Mbps). I'm only interested in Annex A and values which where standardized (and not manufacturer/model specific). The downstream seams to be 24 Mbps.

Does anyone have a trustful source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ITU-T G.992.5:

> Systems support a net data rate ranging up to a minimum of 16 Mbit/s downstream and 800 kbit/s upstream. Support of net data rates above 16 Mbit/s downstream and support of net data rates above 800 kbit/s upstream are optional.

Since Annex M deals with "Specific requirements for an ADSL system with extended upstream
bandwidth", this would in turn mean that plain G.992.5 only supports 800 kBit/s.

As for Annex A, [there is a whitepaper](http://www.billion.com/edu/AnnexM_Whitepaper.pdf) that shows ~1.1 MBit/s as actual data rates, which is similar to what other sources report.

My assumption is that actual data rates were not explictly defined in G.992.5.

Comment: I don't find the 1.4 MBit/s in the whitepaper. Only 1.1 MBit/s. Currently I have ~990 kBit/s on an Annex A connection. Seems that the manufacturer improved something. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Indeed it's more around 1.1. And of course there might be a way to go above these data rates – I think that's why it's not specified in the standard.